# Scylla and "timed out after PT2S" - how hunt the bottleneck?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am running into intermittent errors inserting or reading data into and from a Scylla node and using the java driver. The error I get, sometimes in reads, sometimes in writes, is the well known "timed out after PT2S". I read all I could find about this error and of course I am not looking for rising the timeout, but finding why the node is not responding quickly enough. I have tried to exclude the obvious: it is a single node deployment and the server is not loaded at all (not even when I see the errors). Stats seems to be good (see below) and compacting activity is close to none. No big partitions warning or stats.

**The question**
what else can I look at?

**The context**

- One Scylla node on commodity hw (4 CPUs, 8Gb mem).
- No other main processes running
- Keyspace with one table:
- describe table uzzstore.chunks;

```
CREATE TABLE uzzstore.chunks (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    size bigint
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

- cfstats:

```
$ nodetool flush uzzstore chunks;
$ nodetool cfstats uzzstore.chunks;
Total number of tables: 69
----------------
Keyspace : uzzstore
    Read Count: 13347248
    Read Latency: 0.004633434922315072 ms
    Write Count: 46506776
    Write Latency: 1.3758554237343822E-5 ms
    Pending Flushes: 0
        Table: chunks
        SSTable count: 15
        SSTables in each level: [15/4]
        Space used (live): 17960566784
        Space used (total): 17960566784
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 164689156
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.827822
        Number of partitions (estimate): 117347789
        Memtable cell count: 0
        Memtable data size: 0
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 178
        Local read count: 13347248
        Local read latency: 4.633 ms
        Local write count: 46506776
        Local write latency: 0.014 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Percent repaired: 0.0
        Bloom filter false positives: 59418
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.02055
        Bloom filter space used: 155733448
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 156599748
        Index summary off heap memory used: 8089408
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 0
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 73
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 103
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 103
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Dropped Mutations: 0
```

- Large partitions:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM system.large_partitions;

 keyspace_name | table_name | sstable_name | partition_size | partition_key | compaction_time | rows
---------------+------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+------

(0 rows)
```

- Write error while running INSERT INTO "chunks" ("id" ,"size" ) VALUES (?,?):

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.doExecute(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:216)
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:308)
        at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.insert(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:185)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:91)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54)
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.doExecute(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:214)
        ... 21 more
```

- Read error while running SELECT "id" FROM "chunks" WHERE "id" IN (?,...,?) with 46 ids:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.<init>(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:136)
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraConnection.prepareStatement(CassandraConnection.java:537)
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraConnection.prepareStatement(CassandraConnection.java:529)
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraConnection.prepareStatement(CassandraConnection.java:89)
        at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:143)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedPreparedStmt.compile(MappedPreparedStmt.java:57)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:252)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:202)
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:286)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:384)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.query(Where.java:519)
        at ste.uzz.store.DBChunkStore.contains(DBChunkStore.java:126)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:59)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:31)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.prepare(SyncCqlSession.java:224)
        at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.<init>(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:131)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Maybe try running the query with smaller quantities of IDs?  So instead of 46 IDs in the `IN` clause (which I feel is way too many), maybe try 5 to 10?

Comment: yes, done it already, but I still have the issue once in a while; anyway, it would be a workaround as well, I'd like to understand why the server does not respond without any sign of being overloaded...